# multiple whitespaces inside print

Tags: python, printing, whitespace

how can get a desired amount of whitespaces in a print

```
print("a",'','','','','','',"a")
```

can not be written as

```
print("a",''*6,"a")
```

does not work. Please help

Comment: Your statement is correct instead of the part `''`, write this `' '`.

Answer (score 1):

`''` is a null string, not a space. In the first example, `print` itself is inserting a space between each of the 8 arguments; in the second, it's inserting a space between each of the 3 arguments.

If you want

```
a      a
```

you can use

```
print('a', ' '*4, 'a')  # a, space, 4-spacces, space, a
```

or

```
print('a', 'a', sep=' '*6)  # a separator of 6 spaces
```

or simply

```
print('a      a')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`sep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) keyword

```
print("a", "a", sep=" "*6)
```

prints

```
a      a
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it likethis :

```
print("a"," "*6,"a")
```